# ImportError: No module named flask using MAC VSCODE

Tags: python-3.x, database, visual-studio

[ScreenGrab of error when trying to import db I created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QC1gX.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You either need to install `Flask` from pip, or something similar, or Python is not able to find the location of Flask if it is, in fact, installed.

At your Python prompt, try this to see where it is looking for libraries:

```
>> import sys
>> print (sys.path)
```